# Combining 2 Left Joins

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my database. Here how it looks:

tbl_production:

```
+--------+------------+-----+-------+  
| id_pro | date       | qty | stock | 
+--------+------------+-----+-------+  
| 1      | 2017-09-14 | 100 |  0    |
| 2      | 2017-09-15 | 150 |  0    |
| 3      | 2017-09-16 | 140 |  0    |
```

tbl_out:

```
+--------+------------+-----+  
| id_out | date       | qty |  
+--------+------------+-----+
| 1      | 2017-09-14 | 50  |  
| 2      | 2017-09-14 | 50  |  
| 3      | 2017-09-15 | 50  |  
| 4      | 2017-09-15 | 50  |
| 5      | 2017-09-15 | 50  |
| 6      | 2017-09-16 | 40  |
| 7      | 2017-09-16 | 50  |
| 8      | 2017-09-16 | 50  |
```

tbl_return:

```
+--------+------------+-----+  
| id_ret | date       | qty |
+--------+------------+-----+
| 1      | 2017-09-14 |  8  |  
| 2      | 2017-09-14 |  0  |  
| 3      | 2017-09-15 |  4  |  
| 4      | 2017-09-15 |  0  |
| 5      | 2017-09-15 |  3  |
| 6      | 2017-09-16 |  3  |
| 7      | 2017-09-16 |  2  |
| 8      | 2017-09-16 |  0  |
```

I would like to join this query

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(COALESCE(SUM(tbl_out.qty),0),0) AS Out, tbl_production.date FROM tbl_production LEFT JOIN tbl_out
    ON (tbl_production.date = tbl_out.date) GROUP BY tbl_production.date;
```

with

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(COALESCE(SUM(tbl_return.qty),0),0) AS ret FROM tbl_production LEFT JOIN tbl_return ON (tbl_production.date = tbl_return.date)GROUP BY tbl_production.date;
```

The result I want to see is like this

```
+--------+------------+-----+  
| out    | date       | ret | 
+--------+------------+-----+  
| 100    | 2017-09-14 | 8   |
| 150    | 2017-09-15 | 7   |
| 140    | 2017-09-16 | 5   |
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do subselects for the sum of out and return and then join with your main production table

```
select COALESCE(a.qty,0) `out`,p.date, COALESCE(b.qty,0) as ret
from tbl_production p
left join (
  select `date`, sum(qty) qty
  from tbl_out
  group by `date`
) a on(p.date = a.date)
left join (
  select `date`, sum(qty) qty 
  from tbl_return
  group by `date`
) b on(p.date = b.date)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a96904/5)